# What phrases am I

Tags: riddle, word

> Everyone has one yet everyone shares.
>
> And each thinks that yours is worth just half of theirs.

**What am I and what phrases are represented by this?**

Comment: Any chance we could get a hint?

Answer (score 13):

Is it

> Opinion

Explanation

> According to you 
> [My two cents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_two_cents) phrase refers your opinion
> [A Penny for Your Thoughts](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/a-penny-for-your-thoughts.html) refers to someone else opinion

Comment: It’s gotten more equal over the years though, ”yours” used to be worth [2.4 times less](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny_(British_pre-decimal_coin)) and ”mine” used to be worth [12.5 times more](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/two+bits). (Links may contain spoilers)

Comment: I thought it was ideas